# Meaning of the dot notation in a lambda's parameters

Tags: racket

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2890557/1160770) uses the following syntax in its code snippet:

```
(lambda (template . ids)
  ...)
```

As I understand it, the dot notation is an infix equivalent of `cons`, and allows to create pairs of values. However I can't understand it in this scenario. Is it a way to pattern-match a pair, e.g. like possible in OCaml?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a way to treat a function's arguments as a list, as we can see in the REPL:

```
> ((lambda (a . b) a) 1 2 3)
1
> ((lambda (a . b) b) 1 2 3)
'(2 3)
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The . notation there just means, and the function can take any arbitrary amount of arguments more than that which are bound to a list. That's it.